# Update every day (my code working?)

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate

I want to update the the code inside `viewDidLoad()` every new day - even if the app is not running - closed or in background.

```
let Date = NSDate()
let Calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()

var Days = 20
var Hours = 5
var Difference = 0

override func viewDidLoad() {

let FireDate = userCalendar.components(NSCalendarUnit.Hour, fromDate: Date)

if (FireDate.hour == 7) {
      days--
      Difference = (Days / Hours)
    }

}
```

This code does not work how I want it to.

Answer (score 1):

If that code is run at 7 then the check will succeed. That is, 7 on the device it's running on, considering the users timezone settings.

This code won't automatically run each day. You don't show where the code is but nothing will automatically run an iOS app at a set time each day. Possibly you could send a silent push as a trigger but you should really plan for the app to work when the user opens it instead of autonomously. Any time sensitive offline processing should be done by a server...

---

You could also look at using `func applicationSignificantTimeChange(_ application: UIApplication)` so that the application is told when the day has changed, in combination with your general processing in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`.

Comment: Ok! Thanks. Do you have any idea of how I can make this happen? I want the code (updated) to execute every new day - no specific time needed.

Answer (score 0):

viewDidLoad is called once and once only: When your view controller gets loaded. Trying to call this multiple times is going to get you into trouble.

Usually you set up some things in viewDidLoad (things that should be set up exactly once), and others in viewDidAppear or viewWillAppear (things that might be set up in different ways if your view appears multiple times).

Create a new method that does your setup that would usually be in viewDidAppear or viewWillAppear, making sure there are no problems if this code is called multiple times. Change viewDidAppear or viewWillAppear to call this method. Then in viewDidLoad create a timer that will call this at the right time, and in dealloc invalidate the timer.

If your app is in the background, even if the view is not loaded, there is no need for this to happen. Nobody will notice anyway. The timer will be called immediately when your app comes to the foreground (if it was due to be called), and if your app was closed, viewDidAppear is going to be called.